# Flex Component Lifecycle: validateNow, validateDisplayList, invalidateDisplalList, commitProperties, etc

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, overriding

I am extending VBox to make a Calendar component. What method should I override to add the code to draw itself? What is the difference between all these methods? Is there something I should be putting in each one, or is there a specific method I can just override, add my drawing code, and have it work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This white-paper](http://www.developmentarc.com/site/articles/) is perhaps the best source of information I have seen on the subject.

Answer (score 2):

[Deepa's MAX 2008](http://iamdeepa.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/39/Building_Components_In_Flex3_And_Beyond.ppt) talk was easily the best and most easily understanding presentation on the topic. It shows exactly how to write components properly in Flex 3.

Answer (score 1):

I also recommend this article:

http://maohao.wordpress.com/2009/02/02/6-steps-in-creating-custom-uicomponent-in-flex-halo-framework/

Briefly, if you're doing graphics operations to draw, you'll want to use override `updateDisplayList()` and call `invalidateDisplayList()` as necessary; if you're using subcomponents, you'll use `commitProperties()/invalidateProperties()`.  If you're dynamically sized, you'll need `measure()` and `invalidateSize()`.

Answer (score 1):

Override [updateDisplayList](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/core/UIComponent.html#updateDisplayList()) method of `UIComponent` and do your drawing in it. Use the component's `unscaledWidth` and `unscaledHeight` as the bounds for drawing.

Answer (score 0):

From Adobe Flex 3 Live Docs [Advanced Visual Components in ActionScript](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=ascomponents_advanced_1.html#210754) - great source.